# How can I access a specefic array.map item after render?

Tags: reactjs, mapping, array-map

In my app I render a confirm button if the user has requested to adopt a pet. How can i enable the confirm button to access the id of the user it is rendered with?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BACK_PORT } from "../../var";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function UsersDashboard() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data/users`, { headers: { "auth-token": token } })
      .then(function (response) {
        setUsers(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      });
  }, [token]);

  const onConfirm = () => {
    //Send ID of user
  };

    return users.map((item) => (
    <div key={item._id}>
      <div>Username: {item.name}</div>
      {item.adoptionRequest && (
        <div>Adoption Request: {item?.adoptionRequest}</div>
      )}
      {item.adoptionRequest && (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</Button>
        </div>
      )}
      {item.adoptionRequest && <div>hello</div>}
    </div>
  ));
}

export default UsersDashboard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
onClick={onConfirm}
```

with

```
onClick={() => onConfirm(item._id)}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BACK_PORT } from "../../var";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function UsersDashboard() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`${BACK_PORT}/data/users`, { headers: { "auth-token": token } })
        .then(function (response) {
          setUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        });
  }, [token]);

  const  onConfirm = (userId) => {
    console.log(userId)
    //Send ID of user
  };

  return users.map((item) => (
      <div key={item._id}>
        <div>Username: {item.name}</div>
        {item.adoptionRequest && (
            <div>Adoption Request: {item?.adoptionRequest}</div>
        )}
        {item.adoptionRequest && (
            <div>
              <Button onClick={() => onConfirm(item._id)}>Confirm</Button>
            </div>
        )}
        {item.adoptionRequest && <div>hello</div>}
      </div>
  ));
}

export default UsersDashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as buttons are always "enabled" and therefore clickable.

I'm guessing you want to disable the button if the user has not requested for adoption?

If that's the case simply use the [disabled attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) of the  tag

```
const onConfirm = (userId) => {
axios.get(`data/user/${userId}`);
//Send ID of user by accessing userId
};
<Button disabled={item.adoptionRequest === null} onClick={() => onConfirm(item._id)}>Confirm</Button>
```

Comment: No no, I want the button when clicked to access the userID of the item it relates to

Comment: oh I understand do what @aolivera suggested and pass the item._id to the argument of onConfirm function and add an id field to the parameter. I'll update my answer.